# Excel VBA: Delete entire row if cell in column A is blank (Long Dataset)

Tags: excel, delete-row, vba

I am trying to delete all rows that have blank cells in column A in a long dataset (over 60 000 rows in excel)

I have a VBA code that works great when I have less then aprox 32 000 cells:

```
   Sub DelBlankRows()

   Columns("A:A").Select
   Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
   Selection.EntireRow.Delete

   End Sub
```

Does anybody know a way so that it works on a large number of rows?

Thank you

Comment: IT deletes the entire worksheet

Comment: I just did it with the full rows excel can hold with no error, I did get rid of select though, as in:  Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: so is the sub not properly working because it deletes the entire sheet or what is the actual problem with it? The speed?

Comment: `SpecialCells` has a significant flaw when used in VBA in Excel 2007 and earlier, it cannot handle more than 8192 areas. See [Ron De Bruin's comments here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win003.htm). If all your rows are being deleted then this is likely to be your problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

`Application.ScreenUpdating` toggles whether updates made in code are visible to the user, and trying `Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(...` might save time because it doesn't actually have to select the cells - untested.

Comment: I tried the code and it works for small numbers. I cannot figure out my problem. If I try a test with by filling columns A with random text and some blanks it works. When I have the full data table, it does not.

Comment: As mehow said: What do you mean by 'doesn't work', does it take a long time, do you get an error message?

Comment: Actually, it deletes the entire sheet. sorry for not being precise

Comment: @user1783504 I just tested it with 200,000 rows of random data and it worked fine. If you're ending up with no data then I think your 'full data table' must have no values in the first column.

Comment: +1 for an efficient method, autofilter being the other. But *always use Error Handling* with SpecialCells.

Comment: This macro fails for me. I changed it to make a certain sheet active and delete a row if the cell in Column C is blank. It works except in the case where I don't have any rows were Column C is blank. Then the macro fails on the line that begins with "Columns".

`    Worksheets("Master").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Columns("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True