# Delete a row in excel if all cells are blank in a range of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have been looking around for an answer to this question for awhile now. I've found multiple great resources that show how to use a macro to delete a row if a cell within a specified column is blank but I haven't been able to find anything that will allow you to check a range of columns and delete a row if all cells in that range of columns is empty (if D1:F1 is entirely blank then delete row 1 but if in the range D2:F2 E2 has data in it don't delete that row).

Here's the code that I've been trying to mess around with

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns("D:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I found the above code from this answer [Excel VBA: Delete entire row if cell in column A is blank (Long Dataset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430673/excel-vba-delete-entire-row-if-cell-in-column-a-is-blank-long-dataset)

If I try and modify that code to say

```
Columns("D:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

I then get an error message which says "Run-time error 1004: Cannot use that command on overlapping sections."

Comment: Please do not assume we can watch your screen. *Then I get an error when I try to run the code* is not helpful. What error message do you get?

Comment: I edited my question to include the error message I got "Run-time error 1004: Cannot use that command on overlapping sections."

Comment: Either use AutoFilter or add a helper column to check the number of blanks (and then possibly use AF on that).

Comment: So I have this in column G in my sheet =COUNTIF(D2:F2,"") how could I modify the code in my question to check column G for a specific number and delete that row if it matches?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a bucle to loop through the columns because it doesn´t work if you have blank cells in more than one column on the same row.